# How do I remove index.php/html from the url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, indexing, clean-urls

I am running into a problem concerning the mod_rewrite.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.[php|html] [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)index\.[php|html]$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

The idea is to get both domain.com/index.php and domain.com/index.html redirected to domain.com.
My attempts do not seem to work. The above code is one of my attempts.

It would be great if you could help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is incorrect You need to use `( )` instead of `[ ]`.

Use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.(php|html?) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.(php|html?)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I still get an internal error. Any suggestions?
Edit: it does work on my local xampp server, but it does not on my host.

Comment: Can you post your complete .htaccess in your question so I can check and suggest.

Comment: I just tested this again and it worked well. You may have some conflicting rule which I can examine if you post your rules in question.

Comment: Even when the .htacces only consists of the following rules it the server still redirects the page to [link](http://www.bhosted.nl/error/error500.html), however when I run the script on xampp it does not give any errors.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.(php|html?) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.(php|html?)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: I also tested it and it doesn't give any error. On the server where you get 500 can you check Apache error.log to see why 500 is coming.

Comment: I am moving to another host soon, so I will see how it goes. It works on localhost, so it should work on a real server as well. But I could still contact the help desk of my current provider for research purposes if you like.

Comment: Yes it should definitely work and I have verified it and you also have verified it on localhost. 500 could be caused for ex. if mod_rewrite isn't enabled. If you're satisfied with the answer you can mark it as accepted.